How can I make Firefox Developer Edition launch as the browser of choice in vscode debug?
I have tried every manner of combinations in launch.json adn settings.json including currently,
{
  "type": "firefox",
  "request": "launch",
  "name": "Launch Firefox Developer Edition",
  "url": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\xyx\\index.html",
  "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
  "firefoxExecutable": "C:\\Program Files\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe"
},

Other browsers launch fine. I also checked "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "firefox",  in settings.json but the options only allows Value is not accepted. Valid values: "chrome", "chrome:PrivateMode", "firefox", "firefox:PrivateMode", "microsoft-edge", "blisk", null.
How can I use Firefox Developer Edition to launch when debugging in vs code via launch.json?

To answer my own question, in order to debug Firefox extensions you must make use of the build in Developer tools toolbox found in about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox. Load your temporary extension and click inspect.
https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/debugging/#developer-tools-toolbox
Find out more about getting started creating new extensions and debugging.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions

https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/browser-extension-development-tools/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_second_WebExtension


